# UITableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath , different value from what is displayed in section rows!

Tags: iphone, xcode, didselectrowatindexpath

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

Directory *aDirectory = [appDelegate.directories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    _XMLDetailsView.aDirectory = aDirectory;

if (indexPath.section == 0) // First section
{
    _XMLDetailsView.aDirectory = aDirectory;
}
else if(indexPath.section == 1) // Second Section
{
    Directory *aDirectory = [appDelegate.directories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row +[listOfItems count]];
    _XMLDetailsView.aDirectory = aDirectory;

}
else if(indexPath.section == 2) // Third Section
{
    Directory *aDirectory = [appDelegate.directories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row +[listOfItems count] +3];
    _XMLDetailsView.aDirectory = aDirectory;

}
else if(indexPath.section == 3) // Fourth Section
{
    Directory *aDirectory = [appDelegate.directories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row +[listOfItems count] +9];
    _XMLDetailsView.aDirectory = aDirectory;

}
```

}

is this the correct way to select certain row of value from certain section? because when i didSelectRowAtIndexpath for e.g section "C" , it is suppose to display the value that starts from array (4) . but instead at section "C" , it displays the value from array(0) again. i'm stuck for so long on this , anyone with any suggestion or help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
else if(indexPath.section == 2) // Third Section
{

    if(indexPath.row >4)
    {
        Directory *aDirectory = [appDelegate.directories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row +[listOfItems count] +3];
       _XMLDetailsView.aDirectory = aDirectory;
    }
}
```

Try this, I think it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Directory *aDirectory = [appDelegate.directories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

statement at the start of the method chooses the directory using `indexPath.row` which will not be from the correct section. Try `indexPath.section` for this.

```
 Directory *aDirectory = [appDelegate.directories objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
```

Comment: it doesn't help , when i use indexPath.section . 
sectionA wil have itemA 
sectionB will have itemB,itemB (assuming it have 2 items in that section),
and then section C wil have itemC,itemC . why is this so?

Comment: and when i use indexPath.row 
sectionA will have itemA,itemB,itemC
sectionB will have itemA,itemB
and sectionC will have itemA,itemB,itemC 

what i want is 
sectionA will have itemA,itemB
sectionB will have itemC,itemD,itemE
and so on..

Comment: try this      Directory *aDirectory = [appDelegate.directories objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];